# Delete columns that contain a certain string from multiple CSVs

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a Windows directory containing 100s of CSVs. Each CSV is between 500mb-1GB in size.

Every CSV has 100s of columns and every CSV shares the same column names for the first n columns and the last n columns. Every column inbetween these starts with the characters "R20" (ie. R20150311). The exact name of these "R20..." columns varies between each CSV.

Example of headers:

`id,name,location,R20150311,R20150311,R20150311,R20150311,etc etc....., date,user`

Using Python I want to cycle through every CSV in the directory, deleting columns where the column name conatins the text "R20"...

I don't want new output CSVs to be created, rather I'd like to overwrite the original to save on disk space.

Answer (score 3):

It's good practice to show what you have tried and what resources you have found so far, instead of asking before even trying. Now, that is out of the way and we can look at a possible solution

---

As you said we have to look in each file and find the columns we would like to drop. The files can easily be found with the glob tool by `glob(*.csv)`.

We can then proceed to load the data with pandas as the data have headers with `pd.read_csv('filename')`. The unwanted columns are filtered with the built-in filter function which looks for columns that do not start with the unwanted phrase `df.filter(regex='^(?!RE20*)')`. Here the `^` means to begin with, the `(?! ...)` defines a negative lookahead, so we won't match unwanted column names. Using the built-in functions instead of manually iterating through also makes sure you access the columns in the most efficient way, compared to extracting the columns and iterating through them.

Finally, save the output to the same name as the input with `df.to_csv(fname)`.

Putting it all together we get the following

```py
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

fnames = glob('*.csv')

for fname in fnames:
    df = pd.read_csv(fname)
    df =  df.filter(regex='^(?!RE20*)')
    df.to_csv(fname)
    del df
```

---

A final word I would recommend looking up vaex, which is in incredible new tool withing datamining for python. If you convert your data to hdf5 vaex can manage your data without having to load it to memory until you actually have to, which will increase you workflow tremendously, as data does not have to be passed around between calls.

Comment: Jakob, thanks however like the other 2 answers, I get a memory error `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 4.34 MiB for an array with shape (568843,) and data type float64`. It seems that I am creating a list then storing the whole list in memory before working on it. This fills up my memory.

Comment: How much RAM do you have. Also try deleting the save data frame in the end.

Comment: 16GB RAM. It seems I can't even pass one larger csv through.

Comment: Have you triede defining the types as les than float64? Do you really need that precision? Good practice is to use the smalles possible value you can get away with. This can be defined in the read call as `dtype :Type name or dict of column`, so something like `dict(col1='float16', col2='float32', col3='int16', col4='bool')`

Otherwise, could you send me the dataset and I can test it out? [[send.firefox.com]] for large files

Comment: all columns (bar one or two) are decimal numerics, that only need a decimal precision of 3. (ie. 21.574). I don't need float64. I could define the columns that I need to keep, but would I have to also go through all the columns to be deleted and set them all individually? There are 100s of columns.

Comment: By now you should probably mark one of the solutions as they answer your original question and look for a solution to your error. 
This can most likely be solved by saving the data to a proper format such as hdf5 and use Vaex to process. This way you don't have to load all the data to memory.

Comment: thank you, and I appreciate your help, but I do reference the file size in the question. If the files were a couple of MBs in size, any of these solutions would be accepted answers. I need an answer that deals with large files and doesn't require huge amounts of machine RAM. My 16GB RAM is pretty common in machines.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, something like this, I'd be wary of writing over your original files though, so I've added an edited cursor. you can change this after you're done.

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path(path_to_your_files)

log = {}  


files = [f for f in p.glob('*.csv')]
for file in files:
    df_cols = pd.read_csv(file,nrows=1)
    cols = df_cols.filter(regex='^(?!RE20*)').columns
    df = pd.read_csv(file,usecols=cols)
    df.to_csv(file.parent.joinpath(f"{file.stem}_edited.csv"),index=False)
    log[file] = 'updated'
```

Comment: Think you missed a closing bracket on the 2nd last line? Also I get an error even with that fix: `TypeError: joinpath() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'`

Comment: @TheoF sorry my fault, I wrote this on SO without testing! edited the closing bracket goes after the edited file name

Comment: thanks. Now getting `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 409. MiB for an array with shape (225, 238054) and data type float64`. Is this because it's reading into memory each CSV? remember they are 100s of MB in size each...

Comment: that's due to you not having enough RAM i assume, remember as you're not declaring your data types you let pandas assume what each data type is (more memory consumption/lazy) I would look into the `chunk` parameter and perhaps use `paruqet` files instead of csvs an alternative is Dask

Answer (score 1):

Let `files` be the list of csv files in the directory. i.e. `files = os.listdir()`

```
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    cols = df.columns.tolist()
    for col in cols:
        if col.startswith('R20'):
            del df[col]
    df.to_csv(file)
    del df   # this should delete the dataframe from memory, freeing up space for the next file.
```

Comment: whilst in principal this does work for the first 2 csvs, when it gets to the 3rd (which I should add is 700mb), I get a memory error: `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 4.34 MiB for an array with shape (568843,) and data type float64` This is on a 16GB RAM Asus, and no other programs hogging memory at the time.

Comment: i've added `del df` to delete the dataframe, it should free up most of the memory for the next read. You should test that you have sufficient memory to each each file individually.

Comment: thanks, I did test my script on one of the bigger CSVs by itself, and still got the memory error. So as @Datanovice mentions, it is probably because Pandas is reading each column in as type `float64`